# How do I position a div relative to the mouse pointer exactly when scroll page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found [this example](http://webdevpad.blogspot.in/2010/07/cross-browser-mouse-coordinates.html) on my search.

But it is useless, because when the webpage has long height, and my `<div>` block isn't on the top, when I scroll the page, there are different distances with different `PageY` or `clientY`, so the movable `<div>` can not exactly go after the mouse cursor.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
jQuery("#requestStatusChart").mouseover(function (event) {
  var maskVal = '<span id="floatTip" style="position:absolute"><span id="hintdivlogistics" class="RMAHintdivlogistics">' +
  +'</span><div class="clear"></div></span>';
  jQuery(this).find(".DashboardMask").append(maskVal)
  ShowHintInfoLogistics("abc");

  //when onmouse out ,remove the elements I appended before.
  jQuery(this).find(".DashboardMask").mouseout(function () {

    if (typeof jQuery("#hintdivlogistics") != undefined) {
      jQuery("#floatTip").fadeOut("slow").remove();
    }
  });

  //move current row
  jQuery(this).find(".DashboardMask").mousemove(function (event) {

    _xx = event.clientX;
    _yy = event.clientY;

    _yyPage = event.pageY;

    var pos = jQuery(this).position();
    console.log((pos.left + " " + pos.top));

    jQuery("#floatTip").css({ "top": _yy + "px", "left": _xx - 180 + "px",
        "border": "2px solid red"
    }).fadeIn("slow");
    console.log("x:" + _xx + ",y:" + _yy / _yyPage * _yy);

    return false;
  });

  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any way to do that reliably, given that you don't know the position of the mouse without a mouse event. You could keep track of the mouse position on mousemove, but as this snippet demonstrates it's far from ideal.

```js
function mousemoved(event) {
  var f = document.querySelector('#floater');
  console.log(event);
  f.style.top = event.pageY + f.scrollTop + 'px';
  f.style.left = event.pageX + 'px';
}

document.querySelector('#container').addEventListener('mousemove', mousemoved);
```

```css
#container {
  overflow: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

#content {
  height: 4000px;
  background: lightblue;
}

#floater {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1em 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="floater">Hi</div>
  <div id="content">content just to make the container taller</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot ,but this  is not  i want to get.maybe my english is poor so I  cant not express it clearly,I want to get the  "movable div exactly follow the cursor whatever the page Y position"

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding. I've updated the snippet so the div just follows the mouse around.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this  problem  use another way.
in  X axis we can do  like this.

**content  means  your  main program width,codes adapted all resolution.**

```
var widthContent = jQuery("#content").width();
jQuery("#floatTip").css("left", _xx - (window.screen.width - widthContent)/2 + "px");
```