# jquery mousemove event could not be fired in IE in some position?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a float-tip div when mouse move the pointer go after the div.
but in ie ,I was trying to  move from  left to right side ,in 2 places on that div,I found the mousemove event can not be fired.the setted css style can not be attached into the element.why?
[codes here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31282610/how-do-i-position-a-div-relative-to-the-mouse-pointer-exactly-when-scroll-page)

I heard someone said to use stopPropagation can solve that problem ,but it doese not work for me

```
function stopEventBubble(event) {
var e = event || window.event;

if (e && e.stopPropagation) {
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.stopPropagation();

    console.log(1);
}
else {
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    console.log(0);
}
```

}

so anyone have any  ideas?@ray

[Image1](http://postimg.org/image/6sjoqz3zp/)

[Image2](http://postimg.org/image/nf1901wxh/)

Comment: "in 2 places on that div", is not actually helping to visualize. Can you provide a link or create a jsfiddle? Also by saying " the pointer go after the div" did you mean "the div goes after the cursor?"

Comment: okay,pls  wait a moment

Comment: Btw, I saw this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309678/issue-with-mousemove-in-internet-explorer seems there is an IE bug about mousemove for elements with `position:absolute;` and transparent bg. Check out that one and this one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378497/ie-bug-absolutely-positioned-element-with-a-non-transparent-background-colour as it may be helpful, they proposed some workarounds.

Comment: okay ,thanks ,I have uploaded images.